# Azure Backup Failure - Error in fsutils.cpp - Failed to get attributes

Tags: azure

I re-installed the Azure Backup Agent on three servers in two different infrastructures and all the agents are not backing up. All the servers previously had the Azure Agent installed; I have just upgraded to the latest version of the Agent. Now I am getting the following error in the log file.

> 1538  1908    12/18   16:18:30.215    18  fsutils.cpp(4049)   WARNING Failed: Hr: = [0x80070002] : GetFileAttributes failed for \?\Volume\System Volume Information\Dedup
>
> 1538  1908    12/18   16:18:30.215    18  fsutils.cpp(624)    WARNING Failed: Hr: = [0x80070002] : Failed to get attributes for \?\Volume\System Volume Information\Dedup

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upgrade the latest version, I suggest you uninstall the Azure Backup Agent, and download the latest version to install and register the vault credentials again.
[image]

As to [0x80070002], it is system error caused by kinds of situations. I list some solutions for you:
Delete the contents of the DataStore folder

Click Start.
Choose Run.
In the Run box, type %windir%\SoftwareDistribution
Click OK.
Open the DataStore folder.
Delete all contents of the DataStore folder.
Close the window.

Start the Automatic Updates service

Click Start.
Choose Run.
In the Run box, type services.msc.
Click OK.
Right-click the Winodws Updates service.
Click Start.

Starting the service will take a moment.